# Antlr: How to change the text of a context?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a listener and some overridden contexts.
Upon exiting from a child context I'd like to alter the text for that.
Then in an enclosing context the altered context will be obtained using a typical GetText() call.
Is this achievable? how? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens are normally instances of the `CommonToken` class, which has a `setText()` method.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I wasn't casting the token. I am guessing that there's no direct way to change the text of a rule in the parser especially when it consists of a few tokens. The only way I can think of is to set the desired text in one token and set all others to empty strings.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't change the parse tree, but rather do such text processing in the semantic phase. When you walk over the parse tree you can get all the text and **then** manipulate it to your needs. `setText()` is only a convenience function for simple tasks.